# How could I use file path containing Japanese character for href

Tags: javascript, html

How could I use file path containing Japanese character for href

```
eCell.innerHTML = "<a href="C:\02_代理店買取数Test Allocation\Failed_test_Allocation_85_20170110144943.csv" download>Failed</a>"
```

It is showing '???' in UI browser status at bottom in place of Japanese characters on mouse hover of acnchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your example, you haven't escaped the double quotes, so the javascript will not work.
2. For more robust encoding of a URI consider using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
eCell.innerHTML = "<a href="C:\02_代理店買取数Test Allocation\Failed_test_Allocation_85_20170110144943.csv" download>Failed</a>" //everything between second and third " is something which the broswer will try to interpret as an object or variable
    
eCell.innerHTML = "<a href=\"C:\02_代理店買取数Test Allocation\Failed_test_Allocation_85_20170110144943.csv\" download>Failed</a>" //variable is a string
```

Comment: As you can see "02_代理店買取数Test Allocation" is the name of the folder from where csv file will get download on "Failed" click, how could I use encodeURIComponent() for such case? I tried doing this,  encodeURIComponent(),encodes the folder name and it doesn't work